# Livewire Autofill Input Box Based On Drop Down Selection

Tags: laravel, laravel-9, laravel-livewire, livewires, laravel-livewire-wireclick

hello im new for livewire I'm trying to get input value based on dropdown value.
when i select example drop-down value TOMATO in input show its price.
i done this using jQuery but I want operate it in livewire without jQuery.

Single table having only two fields.

| id | vegetable_name | vegetable_price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | tomato | 1$ |
| 2 | onion | 2$ |

Drop-down view and input

```
<div class="form-control-wrap">
 <select name="student_course" required>
   @foreach ($Itemlist as $key=>$Itemlists) 
     <option value="{{ $Itemlists->vegetable_name}}">
       {{ $Itemlists->vegetable_name}}
     </option>
   @endforeach
 </select>
</div>
```

i want to show price hear

```
<input name="vegetable_price"><input>
```

my controller

```
public function render()
{
    $Itemlist= StoreItem::get();
    return view('livewire.Item_Form',compact('Itemlist'));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your livewire view file add livewire's `wire:model` property so your blade will look like below.

```
<div class="form-control-wrap">
 <select name="student_course" required wire:model="vegetable">
   @foreach ($Itemlist as $key=>$Itemlists) 
     <option value="{{ $Itemlists->vegetable_name}}">
       {{ $Itemlists->vegetable_name}}
     </option>
   @endforeach
 </select>
</div>

<input name="vegetable_price" wire:model.defer="vegetable_price"><input>
```

and inside your controller you can use `updated` hook for your `wire:model` property, also declare your both properties in the top of livewire class so your whole controller will look like this.

```
public $vegetable;
public $vegetable_price;


public function render()
{
    $Itemlist= StoreItem::get();
    return view('livewire.Item_Form',compact('Itemlist'));
}

public function updatedVegetable()
{
    $vegetableInfo = DB::table('vegetables')->where('id', $this->vegetable)->firts();
    $this->vegetable_price = $vegetableInfo->vegetable_price;
}
```

I assumed you have table with name `vegetables`